# Would it be a little but good exercise to construct or find out Breuil modules?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

My question is about p-adic Hodge-Tate theory and p-adic Galois representation.

One of the important semi-linear object in p-adic Galois representation is the $\text{Breuil Module}$. There are examples of Breuil modules.

My question-

Is it easy to give or find examples of Breuil Modules?

Would it be a little but good exercise to construct or find out examples of Breuil modules ?

Any comment will be helpful to because I am new in this area.

Comment: It might help to give a link to the exact definition of Breuil module that you have in mind (there are several variants).

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, I did not quiet understand what you are meaning. But if i change some pre-materials to define Breuil modules, such as some restriction or addition to the divisible module. Are you saying something like this?

Comment: I am saying that you should add to your question a reference (or better still a web link) which gives the definition of a Breuil module.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, yes I got it now. I am sorry that i did not write the definition of Breuil module because it has lot of settings which will enlarge the question

Comment: I can confirm David's feeling (in his answer) that it is fun to try to translate the paper of Berger, Li, and Zhu into the language of Breuil-Kisin modules. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.09036. Please let me know (here or in email) if you have any question.

Comment: @JohnBergdall Thank you very much for suggesting the paper. I will study it.

Comment: @JohnBergdall Aha, I didn't know that you had already worked out the "exercise" I suggested! Your paper looks to be a fantastic source for the OP (and others) to learn how to work with integral p-adic Hodge theory explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worth distinguishing here between two different but related constructions:

- *Breuil--Kisin modules*, which are finite free modules over a relatively simple base ring, namely $\mathfrak{S} = W[[u]]$ where $W$ is the Witt vectors of the residue field;
- *Breuil modules*, which are finite free modules over a rather more complicated ring $S$ containing $\mathfrak{S}$ (obtained from $\mathfrak{S}$ by some divided-power envelope construction).

B-K modules are simpler and easier to write down, and you can get a Breuil module from a B-K module by base-extension; so you might be well-advised to start by writing down some examples of Breuil--Kisin modules.

A nice exercise might be to try to write down some Breuil--Kisin modules of rank 2. There are some very nice examples of explicit rank 2 *Wach modules* (which are in many ways analogous to Breuil--Kisin modules, but only work when the base field is unramified) in a paper of Berger, Li and Zhu from 2004; it might be fun to try to translate their examples into the language of Breuil--Kisin modules, and see if you can extend them to some ramified base fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for valuable answer